# How to intergate PredictionIO with many website?

Tags: machine-learning, predictionio

I am using PredictionIO to built recommendation system, marchine learning with this template:
https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-ecommercerecommendation

For each website, i create a PredictionIO app with a access_token, and it must be type in command line

My question is, how I run and get it in PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the PhP SDK to send events to PredictionIO.

https://github.com/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-PHP-SDK

Here is a quickstart on how to setup the ecommerce engine with an app. 
https://docs.prediction.io/templates/ecommercerecommendation/quickstart/-0pjud
e
In your case, each app would have its own access key and you need to setup an engine for each app if their data don't mix together - i.e. if they have different products and users.

-Isabelle

Comment: thank you, it is my plan, but how can i set up new app/get new access_token automatic in php? i mean run "pio app new ABC" and get access_token in php code